# How to add a line gap in php echo statement?

Tags: php

This might be a easy one, i don't know. I'm trying to add a line sapce in css output. Here is the code

```
    echo '<style type="text/css">\n';
    echo get_option('custom_css');
    echo '</style>';
```

But when i do this output comes as

```
<style type="text/css">\n.button{
margin-bottom: 22px;
}</style>
```

**EDITED**

Since this is inside style tag it won't add empty or new line i think.I want to have a new line between style tags. So tags will be in separate line, no other style will be collapsed with the same line to the style tag. How to do it?

IT should Look like this

```
<style type="text/css">
.button{
    margin-bottom: 22px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Do you want an empty space or newline ? Explain it clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put your string in double quotes. Single quotes aren't parsed for looking special chars in it.

> ```
> echo "<style type=\"text/css\">\n";
> echo get_option('custom_css');
> echo '</style>';
> ```

For example.

Or like other guys said - concatenate it with PHP_EOL constant

Comment: Thanks for the info, no special things will be parsed inside single quote. +1

Answer (score 1):

Try PHP_EOL instead of `\n`

```
echo '<style type="text/css">'.PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Since this is inside style tag it won't add empty space i think.I want
>   to have a space between style tags. How to do it?

Add `&nbsp;` inside where you want the space to occur.

Comment: Why people downvote on answers when there is no proper light on the question ?

Comment: I explained it. Check my edits and update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

`&nbsp` is your friend. Add it whereever you want the space.

Comment: OP wanted new line i guess

Comment: He wrote space in his post. Well, for newline, he just need `\n` in quotes.

Comment: line space he said :)

Comment: @matiit, `Since this is inside style tag it won't add empty space i think.I want to have a space between style tags. How to do it?` That doesn't sound like a line space.

Comment: `it won't add empty space` after this one, i just assumed he means usual space.

Comment: Check my edits. @matiit i want new line by mistake i wrote it as space

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
echo '<style type="text/css"><br/>';
echo get_option('custom_css');
echo '<br/></style>';
```